# python the list has automatically unwanted special characters \n+

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, list

I am reading some data from a dataframe column and I do some manipulation on each value if the value contains a "-". These manipulations include spliting based on the "-". However I do not understand why each value in the list has an "\n*" as for instance

> > ['2010\n1', '200\n2  450\n3', ..., '1239\n1000']

here is a sample of my code:

```
    splited = []
    wantedList = []

    val = str(x)                        # x represents the value in the value read from the dataframe column

    print val                          # the val variable does not does not contain those special characters

    if val.find('-') != -1:               
            splited = val.split('-')
            wantedList.append(splited[0])

     print splited                      # splited list contains those special characters

     print wantedList                   # wantedList contains those special characters
```

I guess this has to do with the way I created the list or the way I am appending to it.

> > Does anyone knows why something like this does happen

Comment: could you provide the date you are reading from? Have you tried using `strip` on the splitted data (basically replacing `splited[0]` with `splited[0].strip()`)? Could you, at least, provide an example of `val`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't nothing in your code that could possibly *automagically* add a new line character at some random position within your strings. I'd say the characters are already in the string but `print` isn't showing as `\n` but as a new line.

You can confirm that by printing the representation of the string:

```
print repr(val)
```

If you want them out of your strings, you can with a simple [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) for all `\n`.

Comment: print repr(val) did show it.. however str.replace is not seeing it. therefore the list remains the same.this is the code `splitted2 = [t.replace('"\\"n', '') for t in splited]`  and `print splited2` shows no difference

Comment: It did work. Thanks a lot. I had to do a simple `t.replace('\n', '') ` instead of `t.replace('"\\"n', '')`